# RewriteRule not including get parameters

Tags: php, apache, url-rewriting

So I'm developing an API for a dashboard that I'm working on. I want to change the API urls to look a bit nicer and so Ive looked into RewriteRule. It seems to be redirecting fine but $_GET and $_REQUEST are empty. Here is my .htaccess file (which is in /dashboard/) rule:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^dashboard/api/1/(user|venue)/?([^/]*)/?([^/]*)/?$ api.php?type=$1&action=read&id=$2 [QSA,L]
```

Like I said, its actually hitting api.php, but `type`, `action`, and `id` aren't available in the request variables in php?

Comment: Sorry, the .htaccess is in the root www `/` folder, not `/dashboard/`

Comment: Give an example of URL and what variables do you want to get. Like this: http://sitename/dashboard/api/1/user/param1/param2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this?

```
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^dashboard/api/1/(.*)/(.*) api.php?type=$1&action=read&id=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}$ [L]
```

Comment: No luck, still no variables in $_GET or $_REQUEST

Comment: Can you show how you want the nice URL to look? A real example.

Comment: `http://website.com/dashboard/api/1/venue/`
`http://website.com/dashboard/api/1/venue/1`

Comment: What if you just simplified it? I updated my answer. The method works for me.

Comment: I've literally copied and pasted what you had and still no luck. I'm wondering if there is any other setting or something that would stop this from properly functioning?

Comment: What happens if you remove `Options +FollowSymLinks`?

Comment: Same result, Ive turned on logging and here is a line from the rewrite logs: `[18/Jun/2013:21:51:04 +0000] [website.com/sid#7fe80baedcc0][rid#7fe804e440a0/subreq] (3) [perdir /] applying pattern '^dashboard/api/1/(user|venue)/?([^/]*)/?([^/]*)/?$' to uri 'var/www/website/dashboard/api.php/1/venue/'`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31973/discussion-between-mattmattmatt-and-pjack)